# Php изменить значение переменной в методе в callback функции

Tags: php

У меня есть класс, в нём такой метод:

```js
 public function quickClean(User $user) {
    $havingIds = [];

    DB::table('rigs')
        ->select(['platform_id', 'RAM_id', 'PSU_id', 'PSU2_id', 'case_id'])
        ->where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->get()
        ->each(function ($rig) use ($havingIds) {
            $havingIds = array_merge(array_values(get_object_vars($rig)), $havingIds);
        });

    dd($havingIds);

    return true;
}
```

Но почему-то `$havingIds` не изменяется, хоть я прописал `use ()`
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте ссылку на переменную

```
 use (&$havingIds)
```

т.к. считайте, что это как параметр функции - то есть копия значения.